# 301 Redirect with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

the following Redirect is not working, but why is the second one working when I place this before the Wordpress code in the .htaccess file?

**Not working:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/euro/stadien/saint-etienne/$ /stadien/saint-etienne/? [R=301,L]
```

**Working:**

```
Redirect 301 /euro/stadien/saint-etienne/ /stadien/saint-etienne/
```

Do I need to add something like the following to the first piece of code?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond
```

Anybody knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^euro/stadien/(saint-etienne)/$ /stadien/$1/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

- Leading slash is not matched in `mod_rewrite` rules while in .htaccess
- Optionally you can capture last part and reuse in target as shown above.

Comment: this does not work. What could be the reason? Do you have an idea?

Comment: So this didn't work and `Redirect 301 /euro/stadien/saint-etienne/ /stadien/saint-etienne/` is working?

Comment: Exactly! This is the case.

Comment: ok just make sure above `RewriteRule` is just below `RewriteEngine On` line.